# Append new html with a onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have this button:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" name="kontakt" onClick="$(this).min('kontakt');">_</button>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$.fn.min = function(navn) {
     $('#footerMenu').append('<li><button onClick="$(this).test('+navn+');">'+navn+'</button></li>');
};

$.fn.test = function(navn) {
    alert('something');
};
```

I just can't get the last `alert('something')` to display
can any tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where are you calling it for it to show up?

Comment: Its in the new, appended HTML

Answer (score 2):

It may be the quotes.

Try this:

```
 $('#footerMenu').append('<li><button onClick="$(this).test('+"'"+navn+"'"+');">'+navn+'</button></li>');
```

or another way

```
var clickTxt = '$(this).test("' + navn + '");';
$('#footerMenu').append('<li><button onClick="' + clickTxt + '">'+navn+'</button></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some quotes got messed up in your append. Try this

```
$('#footerMenu').append('<li><button onClick="$(this).test("'+navn+'");">'+navn+'</button></li>');
```

Comment: This still has quote problems.  The `"` will close the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Working Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Rqu7H/1/

```
$.fn.test = function (navn) {
    console.log('something');
}

$.fn.min = function (navn) {
    console.log('min');
    $('#footerMenu').append("<li><button onClick='$(this).test(\"" + navn + "\");'>" + navn + "</button></li>");
}
});
```